# Input AutoAjustable render Datatable

Tags: javascript, html, datatable

Buen dia devs, alguno de uds sabra el porque esta input que retorno por medio de datatable no se ajusta de acuerdo a su contenido?

```
{
        "data": "ProductoDescripcion"
        ,render: function (data, type, row) {
             return "<input type='text' id='inputDescripcion' maxlength='300' tabindex='-1' class='form-control full-width'  autocomplete='off' onclick=this.select() style='font-size: 12px;text-transform: uppercase;width:100%' value='" + data + "' >";
            //return data ;
        }
},
```

Lo retorno de esta manera pero se ve asi :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se dan cuenta no da el ancho del input de acuerdo a su contenido ahora si retorno solo la data sin ningun imput la informacion me la muestra de la manera correcta la columna toma el ancho del tamanio del contenido. Alguna idea de antemano gracias

Comment: Así funciona el input, por ahora no tiene ninguna propiedad para autoajustarlo